# iCloud Key Value Storage Issue

Tags: swift, icloud, nsubiquitouskeyvaluestore

I have the following code to push the app's data to the cloud and update the device storage using the iCloud values.

However, it does not update the on device storage with the iCloud values.

The two most important values to sync are coins and points, I have include both in the code below in case there is a problem with that.

Update iCloud:

```
func updateiCloud(){
    if (Reachability.isConnectedToNetwork()){

        if (defaults.bool(forKey: "UpdatedLocal")){
            iCloudKeyStore?.set(Int64(points), forKey: "Points")
            iCloudKeyStore?.set(Int64(coins), forKey: "Coins")

            iCloudKeyStore?.synchronize()
            //other values are synced
        }
    }
}
```

Update Local:

```
func updateLocal() {
    if (Reachability.isConnectedToNetwork()){
        if (!defaults.bool(forKey: "UpdatedLocal")) {
            defaults.set(iCloudKeyStore?.longLong(forKey: "Points"), forKey: "Points")
            points = defaults.integer(forKey: "Points")
            defaults.set(iCloudKeyStore?.longLong(forKey: "Coins"), forKey: "Coins")
            coins = defaults.integer(forKey: "Coins")

            defaults.set(true, forKey: "UpdatedLocal")
        }
        else {
            defaults.set(false, forKey: "firstLaunch")
            AppDelegate.firstLaunch = false
            defaults.set(true, forKey: "UpdatedLocal")
        }
    }
    else {
        defaults.set(false, forKey: "UpdatedLocal")
    }
}
```

Comment: Have you put some debug statements to see if the code is even called?

Comment: @ryantxr yeah I've used breakpoints and it does run when it should. I'm wondering if I'm not uploading the values properly or there's a hole in my logic.

Comment: So in your `updateLocal()` it won't run any of the else statements?

Comment: @MwcsMac no it runs them when necessary but the problem is that iCloudKeyStore?.longLong(forKey: "Points") returns "Optional(0)"